# Who is Liza in Noel Coward's 'London Pride'?

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, noel-coward

In the song "[London Pride](https://trove.nla.gov.au/newspaper/article/47486358)" by Noel Coward, do the lyrics "Whoa, Liza" and/or "Oh, Liza," (depending on the version) followed by a mention of "Covent Garden Market," refer to Eliza Doolittle? Also, what does "Whoa" mean here?

> Whoa, Liza - see the coster barrows,
> The vegetable marrows and the fruit piled high.
> Whoa, Liza - little London sparrows,
> Covent Garden Market where the costers cry.

Comment: I'd guess that Eliza is used as a stereotypical Cockney name, rather than a direct reference. I'll see whether my mum, who is a Cockney, and was undoubtably singing that song in 1941, has an opinion.

Comment: I suppose one interpretation would be that Liza is a horse, navigating streets with barrow-boys rushing around (unrelated to barrow wights) and being startled by a flock of sparrers.

Comment: Listening to Noel Coward sing it, the second Whoa sounds like "Oh".

Comment: Yes, @tgdavies, I had the same thoughts. Of course Shaw could have used Eliza (Doolittle) because it was a stereotypical name too.

One problem with the horse is whether they were still using them in Covent Garden ca. WWII. (Otherwise hard to explain "Whoa," though.)

As you say, I also hear "Oh" for the second "Whoa."

Unfortunately I haven't found a set of published lyrics that are exactly like the ones in the recording by Noel Coward.

Comment: *Pygmalion* was an extraordinarily popular play, so I would bet on Eliza Doolittle.